# Multiple File upload isn't working, nor is is_upload_file

Tags: php, image, image-upload, is-uploaded-file

I cant seem to get this thing to work right, I will think I have it and something else wont work.  Take a look...

I am trying to upload multiple files, here is my php, as it sits it always says there is a problem with the file, and if I remove `is_uploaded_file`, it just doesn't work either.

```
include('image.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();

foreach(array_keys($_FILES['ref']['name']) as $i) { 

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ref']['name'][$i])) {
        $time = date("fYhis");
        $destination="./../img/treatments/" .$pageid. "/refimgs";
        $tdestination="./../img/treatments/" .$pageid. "/refimgs/thumbs";
        $image->load($_FILES['ref']['name'][$i]);
        $image->save($destination . '/' .$time . $i . '.jpg');    
        $image->resizeToWidth(140); 
        $image->save($tdestination . '/' .$time . $i . '.jpg');

    }else{ echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
        echo "filename '". $_FILES['ref']['name'][$i] . "'.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you set the `enctype="multpart/form-data"` on form?

Comment: I had not but it doesnt seem to make any difference, still same problem

Comment: What is the complete error message you get? Try to get the error message using `$_FILES['ref']['error'][$i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$_FILES['ref']['tmp_name']` in `is_uploaded_file` function.
Updated code line would look like :

```
include('image.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['ref']['name']) as $i) { 

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ref']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        $time = date("fYhis");
        $destination="./../img/treatments/" .$pageid. "/refimgs";
        $tdestination="./../img/treatments/" .$pageid. "/refimgs/thumbs";
        $image->load($_FILES['ref']['name'][$i]);
        $image->save($destination . '/' .$time . $i . '.jpg');      
        $image->resizeToWidth(140);   
        $image->save($tdestination . '/' .$time . $i . '.jpg');

   }else{ echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
       echo "filename '". $_FILES['ref']['name'][$i] . "'.";
   }
}
```

Note: `name` of the file in client machine is not valid at the server and you have to use `tmp_name` instead.
Hope this would help you to sort out the problem.